# Firestore Pagination: how to define **unique** 'startAt'-cursor for REST?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

This is a follow up question to an [already solved one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71236772/firestore-pagination-how-to-define-startat-cursor-for-rest).

For this previous question an answer was given, how to define a cursor for query-pagination with 'startAt' for REST, that relates to a **range of documents**. In the example below, the cursor relates to all documents with an 'instructionNumber.stringValue' equal to "instr. 101". According to my testing, this results in skipping of documents.

New question:
How has the cursor to be defined, to not only relate to the stringValue of a field, that the query is ordered by? But instead to a distinct document (usually defined by its document-id)?

```
  "structuredQuery": {  
    "from": [{"collectionId": "instructions"}],  
    "where": {  
        "fieldFilter": {    
            "field": {  
                "fieldPath": "belongsToDepartementID"  
            },  
            "op": "EQUAL",  
            "value": {  
                "stringValue": "toplevel-document-id"  
            }  
        } 
    },  
    "orderBy": [  
        {  
            "field": {  
                "fieldPath": "instructionNumber"  
            },  
            "direction": "ASCENDING"  
        }  
    ],  
    "startAt": { 
        "values": [{ 
            "stringValue": "instr. 101" 
        }] 
    }, 
    "limit": 5  
   }  
}
```

For better understanding, here is the condensed schema of the documents.

```
{
        "document": {
            "name": "projects/PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)/documents/organizations/testManyInstructions/instructions/i104",
            "fields": 
                "belongsToDepartementID": {
                    "stringValue": "toplevel-document-id"
                },
                "instructionNumber": {
                    "stringValue": "instr. 104"
                },
                "instructionTitle": {
                    "stringValue": "dummy Title104"
                },
                "instructionCurrentRevision": {
                    "stringValue": "A"
                }
            },
            "createTime": "2022-02-18T13:55:47.300271Z",
            "updateTime": "2022-02-18T13:55:47.300271Z"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a query with no ordering:

```
"orderBy": [{
    "direction": "ASCENDING",
    "field": {"fieldPath": "__name__"}
}],
"startAt": {
    "before": false,
    "values": [{"referenceValue": "last/doc/ref"}]
}
```

For a query with ordering:

```
"orderBy": [
    {
        "direction": "DESCENDING",
        "field": {"fieldPath": "instructionNumber"}
    },
    {
        "direction": "DESCENDING",
        "field": {"fieldPath": "__name__"}
    }
],
"startAt":
{
    "before": false,
    "values": [
        {"stringValue": "instr. 101"},
        {"referenceValue": "last/doc/ref"}
    ]
}
```

Be sure to use the same direction for **__name__** as the previous "orderBy" or it will need a composite index.

Comment: Regarding your code "query with ordering": for any 'name' that I fill in instead of "last/doc/ref", I still get the first set of documents. Can you please specifiy, how to use the "last/doc/ref"?

Comment: Use the document reference for the last document returned in the previous call to runQuery. For the first call "startAt" wouldn't be defined.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you have identify unique document for starting at you'll always want to include the document ID in your call to `startAt`.

I'm not sure of the exact syntax for the REST API, but the Firebase SDKs automatically pass this document ID when you call `startAt` with a `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to do! Do you have an idea, how to figure out the syntax for the REST API? The [documentation (REST/StructuredQuery)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery) is not specific in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact syntax for the REST API.

Comment: I tried playing around with various combinations of passing a startAt field value as well as document ID. I could not get anything to work, but the below does not give an error, so I think it may be close to what is needed.

Comment: Sorry hit enter too soon.
      "startAt": {
         "values": [{
            "stringValue": "Cr"
            }, {
            "referenceValue": "projects/PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/COLLECTION_ID/DOC_ID"
         }]
      },
      "orderBy": [{
         "field": {
            "fieldPath": "Summary"
         }
      }, {
         "field": {
            "fieldPath": "__name__"
         }
      }],

Comment: I also tried passing a mapValue with various values to try to make a document reference, but could not get anything to work.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your research effort! The issue with hijacking the "orderBy" by the **name** (which is always unique), is that it will return the documents in a order that looks chaotic for the user and because of the pagination it can't be sorted on the client.